# Flex Implementing IDropInListItemRenderer in custom Item Renderer using ItemRenderer Class

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I'm making a Custom ItemRenderer in Flex which is for a DataGrid. My problem is, I need to be able to use listData so I can figure out what the current row the ItemRenderer is in. I Can't seem to implement IDropInListItemRenderer correctly though, because no matter what listData is always null for me.

Here's my code at the top:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" autoDrawBackground="false" styleName="gRenderer" dataChange="setStates()" implements=" mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer">
```

And then I have:

```
 private var _listData:BaseListData;
```

And then I have:

```
public function get listData():BaseListData {
        return this._listData;
    }

    public function set listData( value:BaseListData ):void {
        this._listData = value;
    }
```

But then in my set data method I try to do this:

```
 override public function set data( value:Object ):void {
        super.data = value;
       var row : int = listData.rowIndex;
    }
```

But at run time it throws an error saying it's trying to access a property of a null object. In my debugger, I can see that listData is null. I can't figure out why. From what I've read everywhere online it seems like I'm doing everything needed. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you dealing with a Spark DataGrid or an MXDataGrid?  Using a Spark ItemRenderer in the MXDataGrid should use DataGridListData http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/MXDataGridItemRenderer.html#dataGridListData not listData.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are building a custom ItemRenderer for a spark datagrid.  If so, instead of using the base class s:ItemRenderer use s:GridItemRenderer.  There is a public property of rowIndex that you can reference.

```
override public function set data( value:Object ):void {
    super.data = value;
    trace(rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the original poster is using the Spark DataGrid?  I couldn't tell if he was using the Spark or MX DataGrid based on his post.

Comment: I saw that he was using the spark namespace (s:ItemRenderer xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark") in his mxml.

Comment: Well I can and would like to use GridItemRenderer, that is a good suggestion. The problem is, I have this is my Item Renderer:

    <s:transitions>
        <mx:Transition fromState="*" toState="*">
            <mx:Sequence>
                <s:Fade target="{actionPopUp.popUp}"
                        duration="250"/>
            </mx:Sequence>
        </mx:Transition>
    </s:transitions>

And the problem with that is, it tells me "Element s:transitions is not allowed here."

Comment: @slukse That doesn't mean he is using the Spark DataGrid; as the MX namespace is also listed..  but, you're right that you can't use the spark ItemRenderer class with MX list-based classes, you have to use the MXItemRenderer class.

Comment: Flextras, was that MXItemRenderer to me? Saying I should use that?